# Having issues in shell scripting for puppet

Tags: node.js, bash, shell, awk

```
awk 'BEGIN { FS = ","} ; { "puppet node purge  " $0 } ' < input.txt
```

I'm trying to have the command puppet node purge run after it pulls my server from the input file but when it runs in the script it completely skips over. My thinking is it reads puppet node purge alright but does not execute it.

```
awk 'BEGIN { FS = ","} ; { print "puppet node purge  " $0 } ' < input.txt >> output.txt
```

When ran like this it creates the output file which appends the hostnames with puppet node purge.

What is the correct way for it to be executed in shell that will read the text file, add the purge command and run it from there?

Comment: Are you trying to execute `"puppet node purge  "` in the bash shell with `$0` as part of the command? Look at `system("puppet node purge  " $0)` if I understand what you are trying to do...

Comment: Why are you setting `FS` but never looking at any individual field?

Answer (score 1):

When you want to call a shell tool, don't have shell call awk to call system to call shell to call your tool. Just call it from shell:

```
$ cat file
stuff
nonsense
foo    bar

$ < file xargs -I {} -n 1 echo puppet node purge {}
puppet node purge stuff
puppet node purge nonsense
puppet node purge foo    bar
```

Get rid of the `echo` when you're happy with it.

Answer (score -3):

this should work for your use case:
`for host in $(cat input.txt | tr ","); do puppet node purge $host ; done`

Comment: when i tried what you suggested i got   tr: missing operand after ‘,’
Two strings must be given when translating.